# Get missing Ids from a list of ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to retrieve a list of missing Ids in database from another list of Ids in Entity Framework Core.

Is there a way to get this call in one line?

```cs
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TKey>> GetMissingIds<T, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<T> db, IEnumerable<TKey> ids)
    where T : BaseEntity<TKey>
    {
        var existingIds = await db
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(entity => ids.Contains(entity.Id))
            .Select(entity => entity.Id)
            .ToListAsync();
    
        return ids.Except(existingIds);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there is, unless you can somehow manage to parameterize your query to perform this A - B in the database itself. I would be interested in knowing the answer to this myself since I have encountered this a couple of times myself.

Comment: What is the problem to write this in one line and what is the reason of doing that? Loosing readability?

Comment: I don't want to load every ids in memory. Just the ones I'm interested in. In Sql I could write a query which would retrieve me only the ids not in ({ List }). I'm just trying to see if I'm missing something on EFCore/Linq

Comment: You can't. EF supports only `Contains` for  local collections (with small exception). So, if you do not rely on third party extensions, you have written best query. If you are writing `Upsert`, based on on other collection, which should perform as faster as it can, without  third party extensions it is not possible.

Comment: Could you recommend a third party library for EF Core?

Comment: I can, but explain what you are trying to do. I know symptoms when people are trying to check which Id's are not present in database. It is possible to do Upsert (Update or Insert) but you have to understand that related entities will not fall in such process. So, if you have to manage related entities in one GO also, better to stick with pure EF Core.

Comment: I simply have an import function who absolutely needs an Entity to be present in the database before adding some items to a collections of the Entity. Before adding the items to the collection I simply check if all my Entities are already in the DB if not I create them and add the items to the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core supports only `Contains` with local collections (with small exceptions), so there is no effective way to retrieve Ids which are not present in database via LINQ Query.

Anyway there is third-party extensions which can do that [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators).

Using this extension you can join local collection to LINQ query:

```cs
public static Task<IEnumerable<TKey>> GetMissingIds<T, TKey>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<TKey> ids, CabcellationToken cancellationToken = default)
 where T : BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    // we need context to retrieve options and mapping information from EF Core
    var context = LinqToDBForEFTools.GetCurrentContext(query) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

    // create linq2db connection
    using var db = context.CreateLinqToDbConnection();

    var resultQuery =
        from id in ids.AsQueryable(db) // transform Ids to queryable
        join e in query on id equals e.Id into gj
        from e in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where e == null
        select id;

    // there can be collision with EF Core async extensions, so use ToListAsyncLinqToDB
    return resultQuery.ToListAsyncLinqToDB(cancellationToken);
}
```

This is the sample of generated query:

```sql
SELECT
    [id].[item]
FROM
    (VALUES
        (10248), (10249), (10250), (10251), (10252), (10253), (10254),
        (10255), (10256), (10257), (10023)
    ) [id]([item])
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                [e].[OrderID] as [e]
            FROM
                [Orders] [e]
        ) [t1] ON [id].[item] = [t1].[e]
WHERE
    [t1].[e] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> allIds = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
    List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        List<int> missingIds = dbContext.MyEntities
            .Where(e => allIds.Contains(e.Id) && !ids.Contains(e.Id))
            .Select(e => e.Id)
            .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", missingIds));
    }
```